# sphinx-build with differents index.rst input files

Tags: python-sphinx

Can I give to sphinx differents `index1.rst` as argument to build `../build/html_1/` and `index2.rst` to build `../build/html_2/`:

I found in `sphinx-build` documentation how to define the target folder but nothing about specify the index.rst file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `master_doc` according to an environmental variable.

In `conf.py`:

```
import os
master_doc = os.environ.get('INDEX')
```

In `Makefile`, you can pass your desired environmental variable:

```
html1:
        INDEX=index1.rst $(SPHINXBUILD) -b html $(ALLSPHINXOPTS) $(BUILDDIR)/html1

html2:
        INDEX=index2.rst $(SPHINXBUILD) -b html $(ALLSPHINXOPTS) $(BUILDDIR)/html2
```